# type 'closure' error in optim() R function

Tags: r, optimization, error-handling

I am getting a `type 'closure' not subsettable` error and cannot understand why. It happens when using the `optim` function in `R` but not before the function does many iterations. The functions called work fine on their own. Below is code and problem description.

I have a set of bins each with an assigned probability, and under the assumption these probabilities could have come from a mixture distribution of two normals, I want to estimate the 6 parameters -2 means, 2 standard deviations and 2 weights- of the original distribution.

I've written the following functions to accomplish this.

```
pmn2 <- function(p,mean1,mean2,sd1,sd2,w) {
  distr::p(
    distr::UnivarMixingDistribution(distr::Norm(mean1,sd1),
                                    distr::Norm(mean2,sd2),
                                    mixCoeff = c(w,1-w))
  )(p)
}
```

```
fit_nm2 <- function(data,par) {
  n <- nrow(data)
  bins <- data[,1]
  probs <- data[,2]
  wid <- (bins[n] - bins[1])/(n-1)
  dif <- sum((pmn2(bins+wid,mean1=par[1],mean2=par[2],
                        sd1=exp(par[3]),sd2=exp(par[4]),
                        w=e1071::sigmoid(par[5])) -

                pmn2(bins,mean1=par[1],mean2=par[2],
                          sd1=exp(par[3]),sd2=exp(par[4]),
                          w=e1071::sigmoid(par[5])) -

                probs)^2)
}
```

The first function `pmn2`makes a cdf function for a two component normal mixture distribution. The second function `fitnm2` takes in parameters for a two component mixture and a matrix with bins in the first column and probabilities in the second. It calculates sum of squares between the given probabilities and those calculated using the cdf function with the given parameters.

On their own, both of these functions work how they should. But when I try optimizing the parameters with

```
fitnm2 <- optim(fn =fit_nm2,data=rep,par=c(5,1,5,1,.5))
```

I get the error

```
 Error in mixDistr[mixC.old > (1 - ep)] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

One funny thing is that the error isn't thrown on the first iteration, but usually takes many iterations before it appears. I cannot find anything that helps me understand why this is happening or how to resolve it.

Any ideas?

Here is also a set of toy probabilities that give this issue. Obviously they are not from a mixture distribution, but the issue is the same as when I use true mixture distribution probabilities.

```
     bins       probs
 [1,]  4.0 0.042145594
 [2,]  4.1 0.026819923
 [3,]  4.2 0.003831418
 [4,]  4.3 0.061302682
 [5,]  4.4 0.011494253
 [6,]  4.5 0.057471264
 [7,]  4.6 0.076628352
 [8,]  4.7 0.042145594
 [9,]  4.8 0.065134100
[10,]  4.9 0.042145594
[11,]  5.0 0.076628352
[12,]  5.1 0.053639847
[13,]  5.2 0.026819923
[14,]  5.3 0.053639847
[15,]  5.4 0.080459770
[16,]  5.5 0.019157088
[17,]  5.6 0.068965517
[18,]  5.7 0.072796935
[19,]  5.8 0.011494253
[20,]  5.9 0.049808429
[21,]  6.0 0.057471264
```

Comment: I think the problem is in this line `fitnm2 <- optim(fn =fit_nm2,data=rep,par=c(5,1,5,1,.5))`, specificaly in `data=rep`! `rep` is also a function in R, so I suggest renaming dataset.  The error: `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` means that you are threating `function` as a list or dataframe.

Comment: I tried renaming the variable. Still the same problem. The bizarre thing is that the error doesn't come immediately. Only after some iterations of the optimization.